# A problem from MCCME analysis

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

> $X$ is non-empty. On set of its subsets $2^X$ defined a function $A\to A^*$ such that $\forall A\subset X$
>
> 1. $A \cup A^*=X$
> 2. $(A^*)^*=A$
>
> Does this operator always equal to $X \backslash A$?

It's a problem from MCCME analysis I course, [list 1](https://ium.mccme.ru/postscript/f22/analiz1-list1-22f.pdf), task 2.

#### Solution attempts

First, I found a "counterexample" on $\mathbb N$. $A^*=\{\min(A)\} \cup \{x|x>\min(A) \& x\notin A \}$. E.g. $\{1,3,5,7,...\}^*=\{1,2,4,6,8,...\}$. Unfortunately, it works for all subsets except $\varnothing$.

Then I tried an "induction". It's easy to prove from condition 2 that this is bijection.

- For $\varnothing$ there could be only one possible result ($X$) to satisfy condition 1
- For any one-element subset $\{a\} \in X$ there are 2 options: $X$ and $X\backslash \{a\}$, but X is already not available (because of bijection) so only $X\backslash \{a\}$
- For $\{a,b\} \in X$ there are options $X$, $X\backslash \{a\}$, $X\backslash \{b\}$, $X\backslash \{a,b\}$. First 3 are not available, so only $X\backslash \{a,b\}$
- and so on

But $X$ can be non-countable, so induction doesn't work here.

Transfinite induction is not an option as set can be not well-ordered.